# Non-virtual public interface (NVI) with template base class - multiple symbol definitions

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns

I have recently run into this problem when using NVI with a template base class across compilation different units. If I have two classes deriving from my base class with the same template argument (but differing behavior), I get a multiple symbol definition error for HandleData(), the indirection method in the base class.

Additionally marking HandleData() as inline did not change the error. Inclusion guards are in place and correct.

I'm grateful for any and all ideas!

**Update:**
The main problem appears to be the template instantiation: If I put both unit tests into the same file, they run correctly - the problems appears only if derived classes are instantiated in different files (compilation units) of the same DLL (UnitTest.dll, I happen to use CPPUnit btw.)

Base class (in DLL X):

```
template <class DataType>
class cDataHandlerBase
{
public:
  virtual ~cDataHandlerBase();

  bool HandleData(const std::vector<DataType>& data)const
  {
    return doHandleData(data);
  }

protected:
  cDataHandlerBase();

private:
  virtual bool doHandleData(const std::vector<DataType>& data)const = 0;
};
```

Derived classes (in DLL Y, files A and B):

```
class cDataHandlerA : public cDataHandlerBase<SomeType>
{
  virtual bool doHandleData(const std::vector<DataType>& data)const override;
};

class cDataHandlerB : public cDataHandlerBase<SomeType> //same type as cDataHandlerA!
{
  virtual bool doHandleData(const std::vector<DataType>& data)const override;
};
```

UnitTest-DLL contains files TestA and TestB, upon compiling these I get multiple definitions of cDataHandlerBase::HandleData().